# SQLConnection connection error "Login failed for user server/guest"

Tags: c#, sql-server, authentication, sqlconnection

I keep receiving a connection error.  I know that the information is right, as I tried them out with SSMS now several times in the last few minutes, so the problem is in the C# connection string.  According to various Google searches, the syntax is right, just it does not work.

```
try
{
    // Get the connection information.
    GetSQLConnectInfo(ref sConnect);

    // Formulate the connection string.
    String strConnect = String.Format("Server=myserver;Database=mydb;User Id=myusername;Password=mypassword;Trusted_Connection=yes;connection timeout=30");

    // DATABASE: Create the connection.
    SqlConnection oConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnect);
    oConnection.Open();
    if (ConnectionState.Open != oConnection.State)
        return false;

    return true;
}

catch
{
}
```

Error comes back with: Login failed for user 'myserver\Guest'.
Error Code: -2146232060
Error Number: 18456

It would seem that judging by the error message, the Open method does not recognize the user name, as Open tries to use a guest account, which obviusly will not work.

Am I missing something?  I am using SQL Server authentication.

Comment: what platform you are using?

Comment: trusted_connection=yes doesn't match to using sql authentication.

Comment: why it's User Id instead of UserId or User_Id ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove `Trusted_Connection=yes`.  That will override your SQL Authentication (username/password) settings and try to log in as the user running the app.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sql_server_protocols/ms-odbcstr/6c134f58-30b6-48bd-be5b-ed3a8492d870#Appendix_A_2):

> If the value of the Trusted_Connection key is "Yes", **both the UID and PWD keys are ignored**. Otherwise, the UID key has to be specified.

Comment: That was so not obvious.  I simply borrowed a one of the first connection strings that I saw.  I had no idea that Trusted_Connection overrides the user name and password.  Thank you.

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/ - Great resource if you find yourself needing to look up connection strings again.

Comment: I came here to realize that IIS was not allowing my application pool to go through to my DB using `Trusted_Connection=yes`. Had to put in the credentials manually in my `Web.config`

Comment: You need to get Kerberos working to enable trusted connections with more than one hop (client-->IIS-->DB), which is not simple. It's more secure, but harder to get right.